# Excel Functions - Extract string between two characters (multiple occurence)

Tags: excel

I am looking to find an Excel formula (no VBA macros) that will extract substring between characters.

The string contains multiple occurence of the character to extract and hence i will need to extract them one by one in separate cells as illustrated below

Example: Cell A1 = `000000-A99999-B99999-C99999-D99999-E99999-P01.001-F99999-ABCD`

Output expected in following cells

```
        Cell A2 = A99999
        Cell A3 = B99999
        Cell A4 = C99999     
        Cell A5 = D99999
        Cell A6 = E99999
     and so on....
Note: I need a formula to extract these values rather than using "text to columns" as there are many other cells which take up the workbook containing other data information.
```

Comment: Text to Columns, it is in the data tab.

Comment: I need a formula rather than using "text to columns" option. Is this possible?